# File completion while opening the file

Tags: vim, macvim

How can I setup file names completion while I am opening the file.
For example:

```
:o ~/.vimr<tab>
```

I want to get .vimrc file, but get `^I` char if I press the Tab-key.

I use MacVim.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using `:edit` instead of `:o`? Apparently, `:o` doesn't take a file path as an argument.

Comment: Yes; in fact, `:o[pen]` isn't what you think it is; blame ol' vi for this.